# Identify Client-ID in BinaryJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use [BinaryJS](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs/blob/master/doc/api.md) to access access bytes of audio stream (which is done). But I can't see from what client, the bytes are coming from. The only "identifier" that I discovered is `stream.id`, and is not useful for me. The idea is to store different byte streams in different buffers.

```
binaryServer.on('connection', function (client) {

  client.on('stream', function (stream, meta) {

    console.log('new stream');
    console.log("Id Stream:" +stream.id);
    //Declare Buffer, to store bytes??

    stream.on('data', function(data){
      var size = data.length;
      nbytes = nbytes + size;
      //want something like that:
      //console.log(data.id[1]) <--data from id
      console.log(size);
      console.log(data);//type Buffer

    })   

    stream.on('close', function(){console.log("Close connection")});

    stream.on('end', function () {

          console.log("end stream");          
    });

  });
});
```

One idea that comes for me, is to declare one [buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) (previously) and then store the `data` in that `buffer`. But is necessary to many buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already find the answer. And I will Left the code with some self-explain logs:

```
binaryServer.on('connection', function (client) {

  console.log("Enter client:"+client.id);

  client.on('stream', function (stream, meta) {

    console.log("Enter client: "+client.id +"|||With Id Stream: " +stream.id);//Sempre o mesmo valor para cada cliente

    stream.on('data', function(data){
      console.log("This bytes belong to client: "+client.id +"|||With Id Stream: " +stream.id)
      var size = data.length;
      nbytes = nbytes + size;
      console.log(size);
      //console.log(data);
    })   

    stream.on('close', function(){console.log("Connection close from client: "+client.id +"||With Id Stream: : " +stream.id)});

    stream.on('end', function () {

          console.log(nbytes);
          //console.log("end stream");                  
          console.log("End stream from client: "+client.id +"|||With Id Stream: " +stream.id)
    });

  });

  client.on('close', function(){console.log("The client who left connection: "+client.id)});
});
```